# Dividir resultado de una consulta con muchos campos en 2 lineas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla con estos campos :

```
Usuario1    Nif1    Nombre1     Telefono1     Usuario2    Nif2     Nombre2     Telefono2

1          213    Pepe         123456       2           546      Juan        89173
3          456    Miguel       434342       4           534      Pablo       43434
```

Al hacer un SELECT  me interesaría que los 3 últimos campos de la Tabla correspondientes a otro usuario me saltara a otra línea. El resultado debería verse asi:

```
Usuario    Nif   Nombre       Telefono

1          213   Pepe         123456
2          546   Juan         89173
3          456   Miguel       434342
4          534   Pablo        43434
```

Comment: publica tu código para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semejante a lo siguiente:

```
Select
    Usuario1 as Usuario, 
    Nif1 as NIf,
    Nombre1 as Nombre,
    Telefono1 as Telefono
from mitabla
union
Select
    Usuario2 as Usuario,
    Nif2 as Nif,
    Nombre2 as Nombre
    Telefono2 as Telefono
from mitabla
order by Usuario;
```

Comment: Disculpa edite el código porque me falto nombrar  Usuario como Usuario1, y Nif como Nif1. Entonces en el código que me has puesto donde esta la referencia a Usuario1, Nif1, Nombre1 y Telefono1 ?

Comment: En el primer SELECT debes hacer ese cambio, por que el hace referencia a las columnas que indicaste al comienzo.

Comment: Ok ahora lo entiendo. El orden me interesaría que fuera primero Usuario1 y luego Usuario2 pero sin mirar el contenido del campo usuario. Es decir que aparezca primero los 4 campos correspondientes a Usuario1 y luego los 4 campos correspondientes a  Usuario2

Comment: edité mi respuesta en base al cambio de los nombres en los primeros cuatro campos.  No sé como producir el orden que quieres.

Comment: Ok quizas añadiendo un campo en la consulta sin usar como ordenusuario1 a 1 y ordenusuario2 a 2